# Hide pane based on cart state

Tags: commerce

Can anyone point me to a right direction.
I have created a custom Checkout flow and it has payment pane in it.

I'm trying to skip payment pane if the Cart state changed (default cart state is draft)
I couldn't find any documentation for this in Drupal Commerce documentation or through Google.

I don't know what hook is available for this (if there is any) or where to start.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Turns out there's already a documentation for this and I missed it.
For anyone who has the same problem,

You can implement the `isVisible()` function on your custom checkout pane.
https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/checkout/create-custom-checkout-pane